# Keep getting an error during registration [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native

I'm making an app with React and making the backend with node.js. My issue is that every time I sign up (or attempt to log in) I keep getting the same network error. What's weird to me is when I test it on postman it works 100% fine, so it's not issue with my backend or database or how I send the values in the frontend. On my browser I get:

> "register:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

**SignUpScreen.js**

```
function SignUpScreen(props) {

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const navigateToSignIn = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Sign In');
      };

        const handleRegister = async () => {
            console.log('Start handleRegister');
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost/register', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({  Email, password }),
                });

                console.log('After fetch'); 

                const data = await response.json();
        };
```

**Backend code**

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        
        const saltRounds = 10;
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);


        const user = { email, password: hashedPassword };
        const insertUserQuery = 'INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)';

});
```

I've tried

1. Switching from "localhost" to my IP
2. Using CORS
3. adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in my Android manifest android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
4. Switched to a different physical device

Comment: I think it came from no port number. `http://localhost/register` might be `http://localhost:{port}/register`

Comment: I tried that, and tried with my IP:3006/register and still nothing. I got it working on my emulator, works all good (same code), but not on my physical device.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the port of your server in url

`http://localhost:PORT/register`

Ex => `http://localhost:4000/register`